# print array without index-value lines

Tags: php, arrays

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
print "</pre>";
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [home_id] => 51
            [0] => 51
            [home_what] => bann
            [1] => bann
            [home_artid] => 
            [2] => 
            [home_bannid] => 27
            [3] => 27
       )
   [1] => Array
       (. . . etc
```

How to get the result without `index - value` lines?
Like this:

```
[home_id] => 51
[home_what] => bann
[home_artid] => 
[home_bannid] => 27
```

lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum

Comment: Use mysqli_fetch_assoc().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `array_map` with `array_unique`

Snippet

```
$arr = [['home_id' => 51,
            '0' => 51,
            'home_what' => 'bann',
            '1' => 'bann',
            'home_artid' => '',
            '2' => '',
            'home_bannid' => 27,
            '3' => 27]];
$result = array_map("array_unique", $arr);
print_r($result);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [home_id] => 51
            [home_what] => bann
            [home_artid] => 
            [home_bannid] => 27
        )

)
```

Live [demo](https://3v4l.org/T7ghG)

Read more about

[array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

[array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

**Note:** If your data is coming from database, You can use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead.

Comment: @puerto Glad to help, `Happy Coding`

Comment: @puerto probably you are using `mysqli_fetch_array()` somewhere, hence it is giving you both numeric and associative keys. If you had used `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` , you won't be needing any extra PHP functions.

Comment: @vivek_23 Since, question isn't tagged as mysql, array may be from somewhere else. This will work in this case.

Comment: @Smartpal Yes your code is correct, but if the author had provided more context, he wouldn't have to do anything extra.

Comment: @vivek_23 Yes, I've noted your point (mysqli_fetch_assoc) in my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a simple foreach loop and print it.

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5);

foreach($arr as $arr_item){

   echo $arr_item;
}
```